# How to select a default option that will be inserted in database?

Tags: php, html

My problem is when an option selected it works fine but when it is not selected it shows error **"Undefined index: keyword"**

1. How can i select an default value for selected option ?
2. How to not show error even if no option is  selected ? just insert empty in database

or

simply how to prevent that error  if nothing is selected ?

```
<select class="selectpicker btn btn-warning "  name="keyword"  style="font-size:17;">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="display:none; ">SELECT TOPIC</option>


      <option  >Anime</option>
      <option >WTF</option>
      <option >Did you know</option>

  </select>


<?php if(isset($_POST['sub'])){


$post_keywords = $_POST['keyword'];


}
?>
```

Comment: If I post an answer, will that one also not be accepted as correct? Please start accepting answers that will mark the question(s) as solved. That informs Stack/members that no further answers are needed.

Comment: The answer to this is simpler than you think.

Comment: wow fred   you are  worried about getting   accepted  before  answering . good you are so helpful . tho i can see  your only job here is to down vote and mark as duplicate . we are not here to find out if it is  new question or not . we are here to find some help  but we can not unless people like you exist

Comment: With your track record; put yourself in my shoes. And yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: lol u r not even qualified to come under my shoes ...hahaah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
<select class="selectpicker btn btn-warning "  name="keyword"  style="font-size:17;">                 
      <option >Anime</option>
      <option >WTF</option>
      <option >Did you know</option>      
  </select>
<?php if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])){
$post_keywords = $_POST['keyword'];
}
else{
$post_keywords = "";
}
```

Comment: ok it does insert value in database but i am still getting this error "Notice: Undefined index: keyword in C:\xampp\htdocs\****\*** on line 217" where i have $post_keywords = $_POST['keyword'];

Comment: it worked i just removed that line. thanks

Comment: Otherwise you can check value is submitted or not? Then It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have select default value as selected option then remove `disable` attributes in first `option` tag.

For insert empty in databese.

```
<?php
 if(empty($_POST['keyword'])){
   $keywords = 'defult value';
 } else {
   $keywords = $_POST['keyword'];
 }
?>
```

Comment: ok it does insert value in database but i am still getting this error "Notice: Undefined index: keyword in C:\xampp\htdocs******* on line 217" where i have $post_keywords = $_POST['keyword'];

Comment: If You have remove this error. Please remove disable attributes in first select option tag.